# Этимология слова "тарабарщина"

Tags: этимология

После прочтения дискуссии о происхождении слова "варвар" у меня возник вопрос: а какова этимология слова "тарабарщина"? Тоже звукоподражательная?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

тарабарщина (что-то непонятное)- оценочное просторечие от "тарабарская грамота"
Так именовался шифр, широко использовавшийся в древнерусских рукописях.
Согласные в алфавите делят на две равные части, и первую пишут строкой в алфавитном порядке, а вторую под буквами первой в обратном порядке. Таким образом получают таблицу:
б   в   г   д   ж   з   к   л   м   н
щ   ш   ч   ц   х   ф   т   с   р   п
При написании шифрованного письма применяют верхние буквы вместо нижних и наоборот, а гласные остаются без изменения.
Например слово "компот" будет написано как "торнок".
Упоминание в литературе: 
Достоевский Ф.М. "Игрок" - главный герой рассуждает о правилах игры в рулетку:"Сначала вся эта штука была для  меня  тарабарскою  грамотою;  я  только догадывался и различал кое-как, что ставки бывают на числа, на чет и нечет и на цвета."
Гёте И.В. "Фауст" (перевод Б. Пастернака) - Фауст говорит:
"Не этой тарабарской чушью 
От грустных дум меня отвлечь. "
Шекспир У."Все хорошо, что хорошо кончается", перевод Татьяна Львовна Щепкина-Куперник (1937)."Когда вы нападете на него, говорите на каком угодно тарабарском языке; пусть вы сами не понимаете, не важно: надо делать вид, что мы его не понимаем, кроме кого-нибудь одного, кого мы выдадим за переводчика.".